# How to encode flickr short url (base58) in python?

Tags: python, url, flickr

How to encode short URLs of Flickr photos? There is no documentation about the `base58` method on the [official API page about urls](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html).

I can't find examples in Python that are just a function, there are only complicated classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
def b58encode(fid):
  CHARS = '123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  CHAR_NUM = len(CHARS)
  encoded = ''
  fid = int(fid)

  while fid >= CHAR_NUM:
    div, mod = divmod(fid, CHAR_NUM)
    encoded = CHARS[mod] + encoded
    fid = div
  return CHARS[fid] + encoded

print(b58encode(2222223333333))
```

Answer based on https://gist.github.com/mursts/2247355